# filling datagridview from requested data

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I am trying to load an XML document into a DataGridView in Actionscript. BUT I am creating the xml in php from a mysql result. So I need to send my php the user name to select the correct records from mysql database and display them in the xml document.

```
function showresults(e:Event):void
{

var formVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var variableRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php link");
variableRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
variableRequest.data = formVars;
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

formVars.UserName = USERNAME;


varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadresults);



varLoader.load(variableRequest);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loadresults);


XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

}
function loadresults(e:Event):void
{
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider(xmlData);

var col1:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("title");
col1.headerText = "Exam titile";
col1.width = 200;
var col2:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("score");
col2.headerText = "Score";
col2.width = 200;

dgv.columns = [col1,col2];
dgv.width = 400;
dgv.dataProvider = dp;
dgv.rowCount = dgv.length;


}
```

this is loading the datagridview bu no information is being outputted.
the php code is:

```
$xmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$xmlBody .= "<XML>";

$UNAME = $_POST ['UserName'];
// Connect to your MySQL database whatever way you like to here
mysql_connect(database information) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("table) or die ("no database");
// Execute the Query on the database to select items(20 in this example)
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FYP_RESULT WHERE USERNAME = '$USER'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
// Set DB variables into local variables for easier use 
$title = $row["EXAM_TITLE"]; 
$score = $row["EXAM_SCORE"];  


$xmlBody .= '
<Data> 
<title>' . $title . '</title> 
<score>' . $score . '</score>
</Data>';
} // End while loop
mysql_close(); // close the mysql database connection
$xmlBody .= "</XML>";
echo $xmlBody; // output the gallery data as XML file for flash
?>
```

Comment: The way you create the XML is prone to errors. Use a library instead that helps you creating the XML. Also please review your question, it has display problems. Please edit and improve it.

Comment: I understand that there are better ways to create the XML. But for the purpose of this it is fine to use this method. Edit has been done thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You say the method is fine, however, I bet you're not placing the question here for no reason. So I assume something at least does not work fine. What does not work fine? Also the the code-highlighting in your PHP code in question. It looks broken which is a sign that you've got a syntax error - either only in the question if you changed the code or just genereally. If you *develop* in PHP you should log all errors, follow the error log and enable the reporting to the highest level. PHP normally tells you when there is a problem. --- http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Comment: The problem is sending the request to the php page an retrieving the data. the php script works fine and does create an xml document (has been tested) but for some reason when I use action script to read the XML document requested it will not load into the gridview.

Comment: Well, then you need to find out how you can troubleshoot the AJAX part next. Does it recieve? Does it give error? Is it even broken and does not execute at all? You should check those points now.